# Docker nginx with CloudFlare Full mode returns 526 invalid SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare

I'm currently trying to setup NGINX in a docker container (using `nginx:1.24.0-alpine` image) with CloudFlare SSL "Full" mode (i.e. the non strict version). The DNS record is proxied through CF.

Currently, when trying to reach `https://api.mydomain.com`, it is returning a "526 Invalid SSL certificate" error from CF, and I don't get why because this same setup is working on another server with out-of-the-box (non-dockerized) NGINX. Doing `curl https://localhost/endpoint` on the host machine works fine though.

On the nginx logs it just shows this when I make a request: `xxx.xxx.xx.xx - - [12/May/2023:14:26:48 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xA5\xC8^+\xBD\xB0\x8B+\x0CxH\xE2\xB2\xCFm\xDD\xEC;v\x1D\xFF\xA9r\xD3" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    listen  [::]:443;
    server_name  api.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:3000;
    }
}
```

Here's my docker compose setup for reference:

```yaml
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.24.0-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/production.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Port 443 is also allowed in ufw.

Comment: which is the certificate you're loading on the nginx? is it a self-signed cert? or did you get if from cf?. I do not see you are loading it on the compose you attached, this could explain the 526 error you're getting (invalid cert).

Comment: Your nginx is running in plain-HTTP mode not HTTPS and thus is not providing ANY cert; CF's wording is misleading. You need to **specify `ssl` on the `listen 443`** directive(s), AND provide a cert (like @lu4t says) AND matching privatekey for the server to use; IF your cert is from a real CA (which isn't necessary with CF non-strict) it MAY also require one or a few chain/intermediate cert(s), depending on the CA.

Comment: That was it, thank you. It is weird though, I thought non-strict mode meant you didn't need certificates. In fact I'm now wondering how exactly my other servers using this setup without certs are even running?

Comment: CF "Flexible" uses a non-TLS backend; "Full non-strict" means backend is TLS but can use _any_ cert; "Full strict" means TLS backend with a _valid_ cert (either from a public CA like LetsEncrypt DigiCert GoDaddy, or CF's own 'origin' CA); "Strict SSL-only" means TLS backend even if the client side is not HTTPS. See https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/ .